# MS Visio Drop a custom shape using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio

I can't seem to figure out how to drop a shape using VBA.

What I want to do is: The user opens a UserForm and enters something in the TextBoxes. When clicking on the commandbutton I want to load a Shape (i.e. ressource) from a custom stencil (i.e. shapes.vssx) write the User-Entries into the ShapeData (i.e. write a Name string in Props.Name) and then Drop it somewhere on the sheet. I know I have to use the Shape.Drop method but how do I reference the specific Master-Shape I want to use for creating the new shape?

So far I am trying with this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim shp As Visio.Shape
   Dim page As Visio.page
   Set page = Application.ActiveWindow.page
   Set shp = Application.Documents.Item("shapes.vssx").Masters.ItemU("ressource")

   page.Drop shp, 1, 1
End Sub
```

Which returns a type mismatch. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to drop a `Master` rather than a `Shape` so try this modification of your code (untested):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim mst as Visio.Master
   Dim shp As Visio.Shape
   Dim pag As Visio.page
   Set pag = Application.ActiveWindow.Page
   Set mst = Application.Documents.Item("shapes.vssx").Masters.ItemU("ressource")
   'You might also want to add some checks that the target document and then master exist
   Set shp = pag.Drop(mst, 1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to change the name of the Master shape? I modified an existing shape (i.e. Concentric Layer 1) and added it to my own stencil. I changed the name of the shape in my stencil but I still have to refer to it as Concentric Layer 1 to get the code to work. Could not find the right cell in the ShapeSheet of the master. When I print mst.Name it returns the name which is also shown in the stencil.

Comment: Visio has the concept of local (Name) and universal (NameU) names.  The name you see in the UI is the local name, but in your code you're using the ItemU.  Spin through your masters colection and report both Name and NameU and you should see the differences, if there are any.  If you want to 'reset' then you can set the NameU in code.  Have a look at this post for more details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2006/07/27/name-and-nameu/

Comment: You are right. Thanks to the link I now understand the difference. When I try to change NameU, it returns an error "Requested operation is currently disabled". I could not find any documentation on wheter there is another way of changing it. (Thanks a lot for all the help I have gotten from you already!)

Comment: I'm guessing that your target document (stencil) is ReadOnly so you'll need to right click on the stencil and hit 'Edit Stencil' before performing your changes.  You can also do the same thing in code by closing and reopening the stencil in Read-Write mode to edit it.  (This is what Visio does in the background when hitting 'Edit Stencil' in the UI).  For the code version you can use `Documents.OpenEx "shapes.vssx", visOpenDocked + visOpenRW` however unless you need to to this a lot I would just go through the manual method.